# Probability problem: length of new segments

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

I have a line of length $l$. I divide the line in $n$ segments. I do this by choosing $n - 1$ random points (I mean that the $n - 1$ points are uniformly distributed from $0$ to $l$).

I want to add a new random point. If this new point does not coincide with an old one, it will "destroy" an old segment and create two new segments:

```
4 points, 5 segments:
----------|---------|---------------|-----|-------

1 new point, 6 segments:
----------|---------|---|-----------|-----|-------
                        ^
```

The question I'm trying to answer is: **how long are these two new segments on average?**

From the construction method, I think that the answer is $l / (n + 1)$ (that is, the length over the new number of segments). However I'm not sure for two reasons:

1. I can't find a way to prove it;
2. $l / (n + 1)$ is the average length of *all* segments, but I'm interested only in the new ones.

Could you shed some light on this?

Comment: It might seem more natural that after the $n$ points, on average each segment is length $l/n$ and the next random point will with probability 1 cut one of those into two parts, each on average of length $(l/n)/2.$ Maybe try a simulation with say $l=1$ and see on average what the simulation gives for the length of the pieces of the last divided segment.

Comment: @coffeemath I am torn between that and the following logic: Randomly adding $n$ dots, and then randomly adding one more, is no different then randomly placing $n+1$ dots from the start. Which would lead one to believe $l/(n+1)$ is correct.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean... and can't decide on it, so suggested doing a simulation, making sure that what is reported at the end of a run is indeed the lengths of the two new segments, maybe the average of those, *after* the first random $n$ points have been chosen and ordered.

Comment: I run a few simulations. The last one with $l = 5000$, $n = 9999$ and 1000 observations. I get an average length of 4.459, which is very close to $l / (n + 1) = 5$. The other simulations agree with this result.

Comment: As a way to get insight, suppose you initially start with a single point, $x$ say chosen uniformly on $[0,1]$.  Then you choose a new point $y$.  With probability $x$, $y$ falls on $[0,x]$ whence the expected length would be $\frac x2$.  With probability $1-x$, $y$ falls in $[x,1]$ whence the expected length would be $\frac {1-x}{2}$.  Thus, for a fixed $x$, the expected length is $E(x)=\frac {x^2}{2}+\frac {(1-x)^2}{2}$.  Therefore the answer to your question in this case is $\int_0^1 \frac {x^2}{2}+\frac {(1-x)^2}{2} dx =\frac 13$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the new point is added, the $n+1$ segments, labelled in left-to-right order, form an exchangeable sequence. In particular, they all have the same marginal distribution, hence the same mean value of $l/(n+1)$.

But you are asking about the last two segments created, and I suspect there may be a "size bias" effect in play. When adding the $n^{\rm th}$ random point, the larger of the intervals in place are more likely than the smaller ones to receive this new point, so the new interval may be biased to be larger than a typical one of the $n$ subintervals. Indeed, conditional on the lengths (call them $L_1,\ldots, L_n$) of the $n$ segments in place after the first $n-1$ points have been selected, the expected value of one of the two new subintervals is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n (L_k/l)\cdot(L_k/2)={1\over 2l}\sum_{k=1}^n L_k^2>{l\over 2n}.
$$
(The $>$ will be $=$ only when all but one of the $L_k$ is equal to $0$, an event of probability $0$.) It's not hard to check that $\Bbb E[L_k^2]={2l^2\over n(n+1)}$, so the mean value of the displayed expression is $l/(n+1)$ as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the length of the new segments will be $\frac{1}{2n}$. This is probably due to the fact that once you pick $n-1$ random points, you already have segments that are on average, of length $1/n$. Then when you pick another random point, you first have to select which segment, and then pick a point from that segment. We can treat this as picking a random point from a segment of length $1/n$ which breaks it up into two segments of length $\frac{1}{2n}$. Here is my code for picking points in the $(0,1)$ interval.

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


n = 5
total = 0

def f(n):
    total = 0
    for j in range(10000):
        points =  [ random.uniform(0, 1) for k in range(n-1)]
        points.append(0), points.append(1)
        points = sorted(points)
        seg = random.randint(0, n-1) #first point of the chosen segment
        segment1, segment2 = points[seg], points[seg+1]
        newpoint = random.uniform(segment1, segment2)
        total += abs(newpoint-segment1)
    return (total/10000)

X = [n for n in range(1, 101)]
Y = [f(n) for n in range(1, 101)]

plt.plot(X,Y)
plt.show()
```

Plotting the values for $1 \le n \le 100$ gives me the following graph. The red line is the graph of $\frac{1}{2n}$ and the blue dots are the value from the program.

[image]

Comment: You are picking a random segment and then a random point in the segment. I'm picking a random point from 0 to $l$